# async function creates a Loop of requests

Tags: reactjs, loops, async-await

while I'm trying to use async-await for fetching URLs and update the `state`, For some reason I don't understand, the `fetchData` function is caught in a loop of sending new requests all the time when I execute it, why is that and who can I do better? Thanks in advance for the help.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TableCard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {

        };
    }


    fetchData = async function() {
        const urls = [
            'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
            'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
            'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums'
        ]
        try {
            const arrayOfPromises = urls.map(url => fetch(url))
            for await (let request of arrayOfPromises) {
                this.setState({
                    users: arrayOfPromises[0],
                    posts: arrayOfPromises[1],
                    albums: arrayOfPromises[2]
                });
            }
        } catch (err) {
            const error = `we had an error ${err}`;
        } finally {
            console.log(this.state);
        }
    }

    render() {
        {
            this.fetchData();
        }
        return ( <
            div >
            <
            h3 className = 'titles' > React Dynamic Table < /h3> <
            table className = 'tables' >
            <
            /table> <
            /div>
        )
    }
}

export default TableCard;
```

Comment: Put it out of the `render()` and make it in the life-cycle `componentDidMount()`

Comment: You can search for "react render()" to understand when the render funcitons gets executed. As the previous comment indicated you should go for "componentDidMount()". Here are some quick references: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting